# Inversion in apodosis (resulting clause of conditional)

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

As far as I know, I can use an inversion to omit "*if*" in if-clause of conditional.

But is it possible to do an inversion in resulting clause of conditional sentence?

Normal conditional:

[1] If I had not been there, I would not have met her.

With inversion in resulting clause:

[2] If I had not been there, never would I have met her.

Comment: Yes, if the apodosis is a clause introduced by preposed "never", then inversion occurs.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks. Can you, please, elaborate a bit more? When and why is it used? Is there any (semantic) difference between an inversion in if-clause and resulting one?

Comment: Under certain conditions, it is possible for the protasis to take the form of a content clause with subject-auxiliary inversion, for example: _If I **had known** about this ..._ ~ _**Had I** known about this ..._. This is found mainly with _had_ and _were_. There is no difference in meaning between the two.

Comment: @BillJ To be honest, I do not understand why you gave me an example of inversion in **protasis (if-clause)**. My question was about inversion in **apodosis (resulting clause)**.

Comment: You asked about "an inversion in if-clause" in your first message to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with a conditional. As I recently replied in another question, some emphatic negatives and negative-polarity items can come first in a clause, pushing the subject after the verb. "Never would I ... " is quite a common construction, particularly in a literary context, and irrespective of whether there is a conditional before it.

Comment: Quite so, but the OP's concern was specifically about whether inversion was possible in the apodosis of a conditional. Obvious answer, I know, but we are dealing with learners who don't know all the rules of grammar.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can. But in this way: If I had not been there, never would have I met her.

Comment: Sorry, but that's wrong. It can only be "never would I have met her".

Comment: @BillJ:  No, it is not wrong.  Although it is very unusual and somewhat archaic.

Comment: @Chenmunka It is wrong.We're talking here about Standard English grammar where it most certainly would be ungrammatical. Your comment is not helpful.

Comment: user48367 Please correct the error in your answer. _never would I have met her_.

Comment: @Chenmunka and others, can anyone tell me where I can read more about this "very unusual and somewhat archaic" way of using English? What piece of grammar is it?

Comment: @DimanNe: The style crops up in literature from time to time.  You will need to look at some classic novels to find it.